# How to entirely delete MySQL from mac Monterey 12.5.1?

Tags: macos, mysql, database

How to entirely delete MySQL from mac Monterey 12.5.1?

I read articles about this. In all articles it's written that you should go to "System Preferences" -> "MySql" and you will get this window [image: Image 1]

However, when I click on "MySql" in "System Preferences" window, it pops out like this [image: image 2]

There is no "uninstall" button and I do not have MySql application in the "Application" folder.

P.S. in my case, the MySql icon looks like a gear, not a dolphin. [image]

Comment: How did you install mySQL?

Comment: @mmmmmm with a dmg file from the official website

Comment: What version of mySQL do you have - the preference pane does not look like the current version